# Cant connect a QNAP NAS and other services through NGINX

Tags: nginx, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy, qnap

I run my QNAP NAS on this link
->  http://192.168.0.98:8085/cgi-bin/

And the other service is this case is Jellyfin on this link
-> http://192.168.0.98:45081

My NGINX config looks like this:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile on;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name kazir.ooguy.com;

        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/myserver.key;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/kazir.ooguy.com_2023.crt;

         # Additional SSL settings...
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";


        location /nas/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.98:8085/cgi-bin/;
        }

        location /jellyfin/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.98:45081;
        }
    }
}
```

I also open my port 443 and mapped it to the port 9990

And when I try to access https://kazir.ooguy.com:9990 I get the following message:

> Error Page not found or the web server is currently unavailable.
>
> Please contact the website administrator for help.

Also when I am accessing https://kazir.ooguy.com:9990/jellyfin I will be redirected to a black screen.

But at the same time if I am going to access my services from the local links that I've set on the nginx.conf everything works just fine.

Docker command that I run on my QNAP to run the NGINX proxy:

```
docker run --name nginx --network host -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v $(pwd):/etc/ssl/certs nginx:alpine
```

Can anyone explain to me what exactly is that I am doing wrong?